# Using tikz in tabularray causes misalignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray

I am currently creating a table to explain different nodes that I used in tikz flow diagrams. However whatever I try, the column after the included tikz node gets misaligned vertically.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec     = {c l},
            column{1}   = {halign=c, valign=t},
            column{2}   = {8cm, halign=l, valign=t},
            hlines      = {1pt, black, solid},
        }
        \tikz{\node[circle, draw=black] (n) {Circle};} & Text \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
```

[image: Result of given example code]

As you can see in the image above, the Text is definitely not aligned with the top of the cell, although i set `column{2}={8cm, halign=l, valign=t}`

Thank you for your help;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `baseline=...` option of tikz to change the alignment of the tikz picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec     = {c l},
            column{1}   = {halign=c, valign=t},
            column{2}   = {8cm, halign=l, valign=t},
            hlines      = {1pt, black, solid},
        }
        \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{\node[circle, draw=black] (n) {Circle};} & Text \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or north aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec     = {c l},
            column{1}   = {halign=c, valign=t},
            column{2}   = {8cm, halign=l, valign=t},
            hlines      = {1pt, black, solid},
        }
        \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\tikz[baseline=(n.north)]{\node[circle, draw=black] (n) {Circle};}} & Text \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, okay that is definitely an improvement. Thank you. But the text is now centered vertically, although Ive set `valign=t`. `baseline=(n.north)` also produces weird offsets at the top. Is there a way around this?
Also why does the tikz picture in the first column influence the second column. This seems unintuitive/wrong.

Comment: @Philipp The tikzpicture changes the height of the line. In both columns, the text is top aligned, in the right column, the text is just shorter than the line height and the additional space is part of the line.

Comment: Using the north anchor for the baseline will align the top of the tikzpicture with the baseline of the text. You can move it down a bit if you want the top of the tikzpicture and the top of the text to align

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (simpler?) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines  = 1pt,
                 colspec = {l Q[l, h]},
                }
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.base)] 
      \node[circle, draw] {Circle}; 
    &   Text    \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. `valign=h` made the result look much better;)

Comment: @Philipp, really? But you stick with solution with `valign=t` :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I used a bit of both solutions in a custom-command, to keep the table readable. But the other solution works, was first and I learned a lot from the explanation:D